# Any consumer routers with Outgoing VPN support?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, home-networking, nat

When I'm working at home, I need to be able to connect to three different outgoing VPNs, two of which happen to use the same internal IP addressing schemes (`192.168.0.*`).

I also need a static address for my VirtualBox VM so I can connect to my testing web server.

Are there any routers which will allow me to connect to multiple outgoing VPNs and assign different internal IP addresses through NAT? Is such a thing even possible, or are there alternate solutions available?

Thanks!

Comment: What types of VPN - are they all IPsec, PPTP or something else?

Comment: Boot a Linux VM, enable IP forwarding.

Comment: @Cry Havok: Actually, I'm not sure. I'm using OpenVPN but perhaps that doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: @grawity: I don't believe that can work, since the VM ultimately communicates through its host??

Comment: @Brian: It works as long as you can reach the VPN server itself from the VM host. I've been using coLinux as a VPN router for a long time. (Also, "OpenVPN" is a good answer, since it's also the name of the protocol.) It should be possible to NAT a different subnet to one of the colliding networks with generic `iptables`.

Comment: @Brian: Also, depending on the virtual machine network, reachability from host might not be necessary. Both Virtual PC and VirtualBox in their "bridged" mode work at the link layer (forwarding raw Ethernet frames), so the guest may act even as the **default gateway** for the host (and for other machines in the network). All sorts of crazy configurations are possible.

Comment: @grawity: Would you be kind enough to elaborate on your proposed solution in the form of an actual "Answer", so that I can both understand better what it is you're proposing, and mark your answer as the best and thereby finally resolve this question? :) It sounds like it may touch on what I'm hoping to achieve, but I don't fully grasp the process.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a router issue.  Once it leaves your VPN software it will be mapped to a public IP address, with the 192 address inside

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding the feature advertised, I'm sure I've seen expensive enterprise routers with this feature supported.

Answer (score 0):

Any router that supports a variant of TomatoUSB, and espeically those that support Toastman's build. They can be found here: http://toastmanfirmware.yolasite.com/

This isn't so much about the hardware as it is about the firmware supporting things like PTPP and OpenVPN.